# Markdown in Django XSS safe

Tags: python, django, xss, markdown

I am using Markdown in an app to display a user biography. I want the user to be able to slightly format the biography, so I'm letting them use the TinyMCE editor.

Then, displaying it in the Django Template like this

```
{% load markup %}

<div id="biography">
    {{ biography|markdown }}
</div>
```

The problem is, if there is a  tag in the biography, it is not being escaped as django does everywhere else. This is the source output from a biography test:

```
<p><strong>asdfsdafsadf</strong></p> 
<p><strong>sd<em>fdfdsfsd</em></strong><em>sdfsdfsdfdsf</em>sdfsdfsdf</p> 
<p><strong>sdafasdfasdf</strong></p> 

<script>document.location='http://test.com'</script>
```

How do I set Markdown to escape these malicious scripts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to `django.contrib.markup.templatetags.markup.markdown`'s docstrings:

> To enable safe mode, which strips raw HTML and only returns HTML
>   generated by actual Markdown syntax, pass "safe" as the first
>   extension in the list.

This should work:

```
{{ biography|markdown:"safe" }}
```

Comment: is there an easy way to handle the situation where `biography` contained an HTML code sample that you wanted displayed?

Answer (score -1):

Markdown in safe mode would remove all html tags, which means your users cannot input HTML segments in the biography. In some cases, this is not preferable. I would recommend you use force_escape before markdown, so anything fed into markdown is safe.

For example, if your biography is `<html>I'm really a HTML fan!</html>`, using

```
{{ biography|markdown:"safe"}}
```

would produce `HTML REMOVED`.. Instead, if you use

```
{{ biography|force_escape|markdown }}
```

The output would be something like

```
<p>&lt;html&gt;I'm really a HTML fan!&lt;/html&gt</p>
```

Comment: This seems like a natural approach, but I believe it is actually insecure.  Example: "`[clickme](javascript:alert%28%22xss%22%29)`".  For more details, see my explanation [elsewhere](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/14674/971).

Comment: @D.W. `markdown(html, safe_mode='escape')` seems to work perfectly for me right now. Is there a problem?

Comment: Yes.  You recommended `force_escape|markdown`, and the problem is that's insecure: that does not invoke Markdown with the safe flag and thus will be insecure against the sort of attack I described.  See the link I gave for a detailed explanation.  Try `markdown(force_escape("[clickme](javascript:alert%28%22xss%22%29)"))`" to see what I mean; the result has Javascript in it.