# Using markdown:"safe" in Django gives syntax error

Tags: django, django-templates, markdown

After researching my problem ("HTML_REMOVED" when putting inline html in markdown), I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7035916/markdown-in-django-xss-safe). When I try this solution, however, it gives me a syntax error:

```
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:    
custom_markdown requires 0 arguments, 1 provided
```

I am using Django 1.6.5.

#### Template

```
{% extends "blogengine/includes/post.html" %}

    {% load custom_markdown %}

    {% block content %}
        <div class="post">
        <h1 id="post-title">{{ object.title }}</h1>
        <p id="post-date">{{ object.pub_date }}</p>
        <div id="post-body">
        {{ object.text|custom_markdown:"safe" }}
        </div>
        </div>

{% endblock %}
```

#### custom_markdown.py

```
import markdown

from django import template
from django.template.defaultfilters import stringfilter
from django.utils.encoding import force_unicode
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(is_safe=True)
@stringfilter
def custom_markdown(value):
    extensions = ["nl2br", ]

    return mark_safe(markdown.markdown(force_unicode(value),
                                       extensions,
                                       safe_mode=True,
                                       enable_attributes=False))
```

**Clarification:** My question is: How to get the markdown to accept inline HTML? I am aware the safe is causing the syntax error.

**Addition:**
When adding a simple tag `<a href="www.google.com">test</a>`, this is the result:
[image]

Comment: Yes, that filter only accepts one argument, ie the thing you're calling the filter on. Why are you trying to pass an additional "safe" argument?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand (new to Django). It says it requires 0 arguments, but I gave it 1 (safe), and that was the error. I don't understand how else I would allow for inline html. The solution I linked is the only thing I found.

Comment: Remove the `:"safe"` since it's an extra argument it throws an exception on. The filter doesn't take any arguments apart from the `value` which is the one before the `|`.

Comment: Yes, I know the safe is causing the syntax error, however, I need the markdown to accept the inline html. The solution I found showed adding safe as an argument (albeit was 2 years ago), and I haven't found any other answer.

Comment: Here is the solution I linked and am referring to: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7035996/3885347

Comment: I figured the solution was actually disabling safe mode. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have actually figured out the solution is the **opposite** of what we've been discussing. I discovered [here](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/2910) that enabling safe mode *disables* html. So after changing my **custom_markdown.py** to the following, it worked.

```
import markdown

from django import template
from django.template.defaultfilters import stringfilter
from django.utils.encoding import force_unicode
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(is_safe=False)
@stringfilter
def custom_markdown(value):
    extensions = ["nl2br", ]

    return mark_safe(markdown.markdown(force_unicode(value),
                                       extensions,
                                       safe_mode=False,
                                       enable_attributes=False))
```

Answer (score 4):

You are passing an extra argument to a filter which does not need any. The correct call should be:

```
{{ object.text|custom_markdown }}
```

The filter `custom_markdown` already manages itself the process to render allows HTML in the content (with the `@register.filter(is_safe=True)` decorator and `mark_safe` function)

---

[According to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7035916/markdown-in-django-xss-safe/7035996#7035996), there is already a filter for allowing HTML, with `django.contrib.markup.templatetags`, so you should not need to create your own filter (and I think you mixed the two ideas in your head):

```
{{ object.text|markdown:"safe" }}
```

Comment: please refer to my addition

Comment: I figured the solution was actually disabling safe mode. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Oh I see... So the `safe` of the markdown extension means the opposite of the `safe` of built-in filters... *Eerk*.